# How to invalidate collectionView layout iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need to invalid the collectionView layout when bounds change be it on rotation or when the cell size changes.

In iOS 12 and bellow I made use of this code and it works:

```
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
```

However in iOS 13 the function `traitCollectionDidChange` and `viewWillTransition` have changed there behaviour and are no longer being called on the size change.

What will be the best place to invalidate layouts by best guest thus far is `viewWillLayoutSubviews` however I'm not 100% sure if this will be a good idea.

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
               layout.invalidateLayout()
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you call view.layoutIfNeeded() after size change?

Comment: I call it when a user starts scrolling

Comment: Yes `viewWillLayoutSubviews` will work and captures trait, size & split view display mode changes